# How to create a bat file using CMD ?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

How to create a text file, and adding some text to it and then changing the file extension to `.bat` using cmd.

Comment: Why don't you just use notepad (or some other editor of your choice)?

Answer (score 1):

This takes me many moons back. Do the following from command line:

```
copy con my.bat (enter)
@echo please use a text editor, this is not the 80'sh!! (enter)
(press ctrl+z)
(enter)
```

this will create the bat file for you. To run, type my and enter.